# JSON parse error hstore serialization rails 4

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Could someone point out where the JSON error is in the following...

```
"{\"a\"=>\"b\"}"
```

I get the follow error when doing JSON.parse

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{"a"=>"b"}'
```

Thanks

UPDATE

Yep, as the commenter points out, I can't parse it bc it is a Ruby hash literal. FWIW I was dealing with this value when trying to do nested hashes inside of PG Hstore.  Turns out, you shouldn't really do that / that is not what Hstore is currently designed to support.  If you wanted to stick with this approach you can do the following to get the hash value:

```
eval("{\"a\"=>\"b\"}")
```

Comment: That is not JSON. It's Ruby Hash literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not [JSON](http://json.org). If I assume the outer quotes and the escapes on the inner quotes are not really in the data, that's:

```
{"a"=>"b"}
```

JSON doesn't use `=>`. In JSON it would be

```
{"a":"b"}
```

---

*Edit*: Ah, [@falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) says in a comment that what you have there is a Ruby Hash literal. I'm not a Ruby guy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer to convert a PG Hstore string (`data`) into a javascript object :

```
JSON.parse( data.replace(/=>/g,':') )
```

or

```
JSON.parse( data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"').replace(/=&gt;/g,':') )
```